# LaTeXindent fail in VSCode: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm

Tags: perl, vscode, latexindent

I'm using LaTeX Workshop on VSCode to build pdf using LaTeX and I'm getting this error in the Output console when I save the .tex file.

> Formatting with command latexindent
> -c,d:path_to_folder,d:path_to_folder/__latexindent_temp.tex,-y=defaultIndent:
> '    '
>
> Formatting failed with exit code 2
>
> stderr: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Log::Log4perl module) (@INC contains: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 22.

The problem is only related to the formatting stuff because the build runs successfully generating the pdf as supposed.

What I did:

- Opened the CPAN Client of my Windows 10
- Run `install Log::Log4perl` (it installed also other packages like `Log::Dispatch::File` and
  `YAML::Tiny`)
- Rebooted the system
- Checked that Log4perl is installed and it is

I also tryied to install Log4perl through VSCode cmd but I'm getting this wierd error:

```
Running make for E/ET/ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz
to undefined at C:/Perl64/site/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 141.
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 255
  ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe" -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz                 : make NO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Log4perl hasn't been required since March 2021. Can you update your distribution and try again? If you're on Windows, you don't need perl, as there is a standalone executable and you only need `latexindent.exe ` and `defaultSettings.yaml `.

Comment: @cmhughes As written in the answer I'm on Windows 10 and Perl seems to be a requirement till I'm having this error, don't you think so?

Comment: @Mensch thank you ;)

Comment: It'd be best to update your distribution. The Log4perl shouldn't be needed

Comment: @cmhughes again, I'm on Windows 10 (updated of course) and I run also the MikTex update.

Comment: Perhaps one of the options at https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376?s=09 in particular https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376?s=09#issuecomment-432479571

Comment: Yes the last one is working, I figured it out by myself but thanks anyway for the suggestion and the time spent in helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to Latex Workshop VSCode extension settings and editing the "Latex-workshop › Latexindent: Path" matching the latexindent.exe path was enough to solve all the errors.